# How to determine if a pull request is a draft inside travis build

Tags: travis-ci, pull-request

Is there a way to detect if a github pull request is a [draft pull-request](https://github.blog/2019-02-14-introducing-draft-pull-requests/) within a travis build? There is a [`draft` label](https://changelog.travis-ci.com/draft-pull-requests-support-105121) in travis' UI. This is also stated in the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/pull-requests/).

But there seems to be no [environment variable](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables) inside a build, that tells if the current PR is a draft PR. Is there any other way to tell?